# How can I bind the second argument in a function but not the first (in an elegant way)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is there a way in Haskell to bind the second argument but not the first of a function without using lambda functions or defining another "local" function?

Example. I have a binary function like:

```
sub :: Int -> Int -> Int
sub x y = x - y
```

Now if I want to bind the first argument, I can do so easily using (sub someExpression):

```
mapSubFrom5 x = map (sub 5) x

*Main> mapSubFrom5 [1,2,3,4,5]
[4,3,2,1,0]
```

That works fine if I want to bind the first n arguments without "gap".

If I want to bind the second argument but not the first, the two options I am aware of are more verbose:

Either via another, local, function:

```
mapSub5 x = map sub5 x
    where sub5 x = sub x 5

*Main> mapSub5 [1,2,3,4,5]
[-4,-3,-2,-1,0]
```

Or using lambda:

```
mapSub5 x = map (\x -> sub x 5) x
```

While both are working fine, I like the elegance of "sub 5" and wonder if there is a similarly elegant way to bind the n-th (n > 1) argument of a function?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`flip`, which produces a new function with the first two arguments inversed, has already been mentioned as a straigtforward solution.

However, it's worth noting that Haskell defines a nice infix syntax for binary operators.

First of all, it's simply

```
sub = (-)
```

With parentheses around, all operators are - syntactially too - ordinary functions. Now we can curry operators with some special syntax. Binding to the first operand:

```
addOne = (1 +)
```

... and to the second

```
half = (/ 2)
```

Thus your code becomes

```
map (-5) [1..5]
```

Unfortunately, `-5` is a number literal, but you get the point. :) Now since we can turn any function into a binary operator by putting backticks around it like in

```
f x y == x `f` y
```

we can use this special operator syntax to write

```
map (`sub` 5) [1..5]
```

---

**Note:** Currying the first argument is common, the second one - as in your case - nicely possible. But: I wouldn't do that for futher arguments. Haskell functions are written in a style that the common ones to curry are in the front for exactly that reason.

Using some special syntax for further arguments feels much too implicit for me. Just use the lambda and give the variables descriptive names.

Comment: Because `-5` is a number, the haskell makers even added a `subtract` function which is defined as `subtract = flip (-)` so that you can write `map (subtract 5)`. It's more readable, though.

Comment: Also, a corollary to the final note: If you often want to partially apply later arguments to a function you wrote yourself, don't hesitate to change the order directly! It's relatively rare for a function to have three or more arguments that are all likely to be used that way.

Answer (score 10):

For n=2 only another way to bind:

```
mapSub5 x = map (`sub` 5) x
```

Answer (score 9):

How to bind the second argument:

```
div2 = flip div 2

ghci> div2 10
5
```

In your case you can write

```
ghci> map (flip (-) 5) [1..5]
[-4,-3,-2,-1,0]
```

Note that in Haskell you can write operators in prefix form as `(-)`. It is the same as `sub` in your question.

Comment: (I know about (-). sub was just a primitive example function) Thanks for pointing to flip. That works at least for the 2nd argument case. Although I guess I find the more verbose where/lambda ways more readable.